# Linux's "ip route" not shows the route for dev lo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, routing

Ubuntu 20.
I do

```
ip -4 route add local 172.20.30.0/24 dev lo
```

It's OK.
Again - I got

```
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

This is OK.

But 'ip route' not shows this rule, neither 'netstat -rn', neither 'route -en'.

Where can I view this rule?

Comment: Check `ip addr` instead. Either way, loopback is special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lo` interface is a virtual interface.  It's only purpose is to return all the packets it receives.

You may check the routing table associated with it using the command:

```
ip route show table local
```

This way you will be able to check if the route you are trying to add is actually there.